# Count distinct in for xml path

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below query to get count of total number of employees that visited the outlet in each day of the month so the output will be like below

```
Outlet     12/01/2017 12/02/2017 -- rest days of the month
Outlet1        6       5
Outlet2        4       3
```

but the issue i have some duplicate values so i have to use count distinct
in the below query but it give the following error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'distinct'.

Note if i removed distinct the query works fine

**Query**

```
DECLARE @cols AS nvarchar(max),
        @query AS nvarchar(max)
SELECT
  @cols = STUFF((SELECT
    ',' + QUOTENAME(LogDate)
  FROM dbo.AccessLog 
  WHERE  month(CONVERT(datetime,LogDate)) = 12 
    and year(CONVERT(datetime,LogDate)) = 2017 
    and AccessLog.InOut = 0 
  GROUP BY LogDate
  ORDER BY LogDate
  FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE)
  .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

SET @query = 'SELECT   abr as Outlet,' + @cols + 
            ' from (select abr,LogDate,TerminalID,EmployeeID 
                    from AccessLog  
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Outlet 
                       ON dbo.Outlet.Code = dbo.AccessLog.TerminalID 
                    where AccessLog.InOut=0 
                      and month(CONVERT(datetime,LogDate)) = ''12'' 
                      and year(CONVERT(datetime,LogDate)) = ''2017'') x 
              pivot (count(distinct EmployeeID) 
             for LogDate in (' + @cols + ') ) p '

EXECUTE (@query);
```

Comment: I would start simplifying the select statement to the minimal version that still shows the problem. More often than not, this has solved my problem.

Comment: What is the final result on `@query`? Just print it and debug it.

Comment: not related to your problem. But is better use `where datetime >= 2017-12-01 and datetime < 2018-01-01` so your query can use index.

Comment: If you remove the `distinct` works OK ?? again if we could see the `@query` content would be much easier

Comment: yes if i removed  distinct  its works

Comment: i am trying to get @query content but i am not enable to get it